# CGMutablePathRef to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

How to add CGMutablePathRef to NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CGMutablePath path = <... your path ...>;
[mutableArray addObject:(id)path];
```

`CGPath` and `CGMutablePath` are just opaque CFType object types, and those can be added (via casting to `id`) to any Cocoa container classes that are toll-free bridged to their CoreFoundation counter-parts.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap CGMutablePathRef to a NSValue and store it in array. Then when needed unwrap it:

```
//Wrap
NSValue *pathValue = [NSValue valueWithPointer: path];
[array addObject:pathValue];

//Unwrap
NSValue *pathValue = [array objectAtIndex: index];
CGMutablePathRef path = [pathValue pointerValue];
```

Note that `valueWithPointer:` method does not affect object's retain count so you must not release your path when adding to array (release it later when it is not needed anymore)