# UIBezierPath draw line representation

Tags: uiview, drawing, representation, uibezierpath

I wrote a simple drawing code using UIBezierPath and the `-touches...` methods of UIView. The drawing works great, but I made some bad experiences.

1. When I'm painting very slow, it works great. But the more fast I draw, the more edgy the line gets. So how do I like "smooth" them to become less edgy (more points)?
2. When I use `setLineWidth` with high line widths, the line become very *ugly*.

Here is an image to show what *ugly* actually means:
[image: This actually means "ugly"]

Why does it draw fat line in that way?!

*EDIT: here some code*

```
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for(UIBezierPath *path in pathArray) {
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [path setLineWidth:50.0];
        [path stroke];
    }
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    startPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:startPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]];
    if(isDrawing) {
        [pathArray removeLastObject];
    }
    else {
        isDrawing = YES;
    }
    [pathArray addObject:path];
    [path close];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    isDrawing = NO;
}
```

I hope that somebody can help me with these issues. THANKS a lot, greets, Julian

Comment: Can you share the code that sets up the path?

Comment: I added some code. I wrote it from memory, so it might be misspelled at some point

Answer (score 1):

Mmmmh, I'm not going to address performance issues with your implementation in this thread, but take a look at `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` in UIView once you get the basics working.

I think you're basically trying to take out the last created path from your array and replace it with a new one for as long as you're moving.

You should try to put a `CGMutablePathRef` in your array instead (take a look here for that [CGMutablePathRef to NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133063/cgmutablepathref-to-nsmutablearray)).

The basic flow would be something like:

1. `touchesBegan`:

   1. Create the `CGMutablePathRef`
   2. Call moveToPoint
   3. Store in the array
2. `touchesMoved`:

   1. Get the lastObject from your array (i.e. the `CGMutablePathRef`)
   2. Call addLineToPoint
   3. `[self setNeedsDisplay]`

Then in drawInRect, iterate through your paths and paint them.

Again, this will be slow at first, then you need to optimize. `CGLayerRef` can help. `setNeedsDisplayInRect` most definitely will also.